subscribing event with event_bus using appData.eventBus.on().listen((event) {...} not working in flutter
I have a file name AppData.dart as below:
class TestEventBus {
  final String message;
  TestEventBus(this.message);
}

class AppData {
  // Create a private static instance of AppData
  static final AppData _instance = AppData._internal();
  
 final EventBus eventBus = EventBus();
  void broadcastTestEventBus(String message) {
    print("Broadcasting update: $message");  // Debug print
    eventBus.fire(TestEventBus(message));
  }
  Future<void> asyncInit() async {
    broadcastTestEventBus("Test message");
  }
}
final AppData appData = AppData();

Now I am trying to subscribe the event of event bus in a  screen HomeScreen.dart like below
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    print("Setting up event listener");  // Debug print

    // Subscribe to the event
    appData.eventBus.on<TestEventBus>().listen((event) {
      try {
        //print('Received event with message: ${event.message}');
        print(event.runtimeType);
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error handling event: $e');
      }
    });

  }

It goes through eventBus.fire(TestEventBus(message)); and prints the log inside HomeScreen print("Setting up event listener");  but neither visiting the line appData.eventBus.on<TestEventBus>().listen((event) {  nor printing logs under  try-catch
